# Does strcpy'ing a string into into a larger char array cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Hey all, just wondering whether the following would cause a memory leak?

```
char* a = "abcd"
char* b = new char[80];

strcpy(b, a);

delete[] b;
```

Will it delete the whole block of 80 or just the 4 characters copied into it by strcpy? Thanks!

Comment: now you understand `new/delete`, write the same logic using `std::string` as an exercise... Since this is C++, avoid CRT wherever you can.  std::string manages its own memory for you and you don't have to worry about `strlen(a) > 79`.

Comment: I get new/delete (most of the time) just unfortunately I don't have the option of std::string in this case (it's going into another fixed function which handles the delete[] for me). I was mainly concerned whether it would stop deleting at a null terminator but I guess that's not an issue. It's been a while since I used C so thanks for the refresher!

Comment: understood - that's an unusual API design to require memory to be owned by the called function... btw don't confuse C++ with C unless you want to rile up the natives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You allocated 80 bytes into `b`, so `delete[]` will free 80 bytes. What you did with the array in the meantime is irrelevant.

(Unless, of course, you corrupted the heap, in which case `delete[]` will probably crash.)

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out, since `b` is an array, you need to use `delete[] b;` instead of `delete b;`. Some implementations might let you get away with that, but others won't, and it would still be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

A memory leak is when you don't free memory. Just because you allocated more than you need doesn't mean it a memory leak. What you do with your memory is up to you.

Though that should 1) be `delete [] b;`, or you get undefined behavior, and 2) Be a `std::string` or `std::vector`, so you don't both manage and use a resource.

Answer (score 4):

The allocation system will take care of remembering how long the allocations are. The contents don't matter at all.

However, you do need to call the [right delete operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/). In this case since you allocated new[] you need to delete[].

The last line should be:

```
delete[] b;
```

If you allocate one item use delete, if you're allocating an array use delete[].

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged C++, here's the C++ version - good to understand memory management via `new/delete`, but better to avoid doing it by hand using RAII.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a("abcd");
    string aCopy(a);
    cout << aCopy << endl;

    const char* b(aCopy.c_str());
    cout << b << endl;
}
```